# Запретить индексации с одного из доменов

Tags: html, robots.txt

Есть сайт, который доступен по следующим доменам:

http://www.consult-unity.ru/
https://consult-unity.ru
https://studentprograms.ru

Как сделать запрет на индексацию по доменам:

http://www.consult-unity.ru/
https://consult-unity.ru

В итоге нужно, чтобы сайт был доступен для индексации только по домену https://studentprograms.ru

Comment: Разделяй robots.txt на несколько доменов.

Comment: А как это сделать? Можно пример?

Comment: а что у вас за движок?

Comment: joomla используется

Comment: Позже попробую что-нибудь придумать для джумлы

Answer (score 0):

На обоих сайтах http://www.consult-unity.ru/ https://consult-unity.ru разместите robots.txt с содержанием

> User-agent: * 
>   Disallow: /